# how to refer to an image in intellij?

Tags: java, scala

Until now I used a path on my local desktop where the image is physically there:

```
val addInvoiceScanButton: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.className("cloudinary-fileupload"))
    addInvoiceScanButton.sendKeys("/Users/username/Desktop/111.png")
```

Now, I added the 111.png image to my resources folder in intellij, and now I want to know how do I refer to it instead to my photo in the desktop..?

thanks

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the good old Java API to find the full path a resource file:

```
val filePath: String = this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("111.png").getFile
```

And then continue as before:

```
addInvoiceScanButton.sendKeys(filePath)
```